# Autoregistration in two groups

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

On Prestashop 1.6 I have a custom group.

How can I auto register new customers into two groups?
The default group and my new group?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your code to the actionCustomerAccountAdd hook. At the $params array you have index "newCustomer" which is a Customer object. Here's a simple example:

```
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params)
{
    $customer = $params['newCustomer'];
    $customer->addGroups(array(10));
}
```

Where 10 is the ID of the group.